# How to execute many files in the same directory in a minimal, DRY, pretty way?

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, executable, subshell, syntax

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a localization file, a file that executes many files, that I got after downloading my own GitHub project to my machine.

This file contains a Bash script, and is named `localize.sh`. I run it in a subsession via `~/${repo}/localize.sh`.

The file contains many lines, all with the same basic pattern (see below), to execute all relevant files in sub-session.

This is the actual content of that file:

```
#!/bin/bash
~/${repo}/apt/security.sh
~/${repo}/apt/lemp.sh
~/${repo}/apt/certbot.sh
~/${repo}/apt/misc.sh

~/${repo}/third-party/pma.sh
~/${repo}/third-party/wp-cli.sh

~/${repo}/conf/nginx.sh
~/${repo}/conf/php.sh
~/${repo}/conf/crontab.sh

~/${repo}/local/tdm.sh
```

One can notice the repetitive `~/${repo}/` pattern.

It isn't a big problem, but it would still be good to reduce these redundant characters as this file should become larger.

What is the most minimal way possible to achieve a DRY ([Don’t Repeat Yourself](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) version of that code?

One single long line isn't something I personally would want to use, in this case.

Edit: By principle, there aren't and there shouldn't be any other files in the listed directories, besides the files listed in `localize.sh`.

---

Also, it might be that the name `localize.sh`, as well as calling the action of the file `localization` is a bad approach; Please criticize me if you think it's bad, in a side note.

Comment: does the order of scripts execution matter?

Comment: Yes. This is why it was important for me to separate them into "stacks" with the empty lines between.

Comment: Maybe: `~/${repo}/**/*.sh`? Edit: you’ll need file globbing enabled.

Comment: Are the names of the `.sh` files fixed?

Comment: @roaima what do you mean by fixed? They're just there, aren't changing and shouldn't be changed.

Comment: So that's a "no". Shame; I was hoping you could prefix the filenames with an ordering, such as `00_security.sh`, `01_lemp.sh`, `03_certbot.sh`, `90_misc.sh`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Answer by Marc, I assume the shortest solution would be something like this:

```
$ myPath="$HOME/$repo"; find ${path} -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec {} \;
file_1
file_2
...
```

Comment: `find` will very likely not give you the files in any particular order. You could rig something with `sort`, but it'd still give you the alphabetical order.

Answer (score 8):

It’s not clear whether you’re running *all* the scripts in the relevant directories, but if you are, you might find `run-parts` useful:

```
for subdir in apt third-party conf local
do
    run-parts --regex '\.sh$' ~/${repo}/${subdir}
done
```

Note that this will run the scripts in alphanumeric order inside each directory, so if order is significant inside a subdirectory you’ll need to rename them (or number them). You can see what `run-parts` will do ahead of time by running it with the `--test` option:

```
apt/certbot.sh
apt/lemp.sh
apt/misc.sh
apt/security.sh
third-party/pma.sh
third-party/wp-cli.sh
conf/crontab.sh
conf/nginx.sh
conf/php.sh
local/tdm.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Whats about a simple and short 'find ${repo} -exec {} \;'?

My example scripts just echo "foo" or "bar" or "baz":

```
$ repo=~/scripts/bash/foo; find ${repo} -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec {} \;
foo
baz
bar
```

you can even alias' to shorten it:

```
$ alias run_myscripts='repo=~/scripts/bash/foo; find ${repo} -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec {} \;'
```

or 
    $ alias run_myscripts='find ~/scripts/bash/foo -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec {} \;'

Then just run

```
run_myscripts
```

Just notices that the files need the execute flag. If they don't have it or you are unsure, you just need to extend the 'find ... -exec' command like this:

```
find ${repo} -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec bash {} \;'
```

Edit:
Ok, didn't notice that the order should be keep. This will change it a bit and I think a good way is to place the order in a textfile and wrap a "while read line" around an execute line.

```
while read line; do 
    bash ~/${repo}/$line
done < ordered_scripts.txt
```

in ordered_scripts.txt you can define the correct order.

```
apt/security.sh
apt/lemp.sh
apt/certbot.sh
apt/misc.sh
third-party/pma.sh
third-party/wp-cli.sh
conf/nginx.sh
conf/php.sh
conf/crontab.sh
local/tdm.sh
```

Comment: In a script, a shell _function_ would be more apropriate.

Comment: It will not keep the order as given by OP: "The order of everything should be as I presented".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all scripts are located within the common parent directory `~/${repo}` you can put them into an array and loop over it:

```
SCRIPTS=(apt/security.sh apt/lemp.sh apt/certbot.sh apt/misc.sh
         tp/pma.sh tp/wp-cli.sh conf/nginx.sh conf/php.sh conf/crontab.sh
         local/tdm.sh)

for SCRIPT in ${SCRIPTS[@]}; do
    ~/${repo}/${SCRIPT}
done
```

Comment: This does have the upside that you have total control over the order of the filenames. You could also use brace expansion to avoid repeating the directory names, though not everyone might find it pretty: `apt/{security.sh,lemp.sh,certbot.sh,misc.sh}` etc...

Comment: @ilkkachu - he did ask for minimal. (also  you could do `apt/{misc,lemp...}.sh` to save a few bytes)

Comment: @DarkHeart, yeah, depends on what they mean with "minimal". Least amount of bytes or least amount of distinct features used...

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel:

```
parallel ::: ~/${repo}/*/*.sh
```

If it needs to be serial:

```
parallel -j1 ::: ~/${repo}/*/*.sh
```

This will run the scripts in alphanumeric order, so if order is significant rename the dirs and folders like this: `01_apt/01_security.sh` Use `--dry-run` to see what would be run.

If this matches too many files (e.g. other dirs), mention the dirs directly.

```
parallel ::: ~/${repo}/{apt,third-party,conf,local}/*.sh
```

If the order matters:

```
parallel -j1 ::: \
  ~/${repo}/{apt/{security,lemp,certbot,misc},third-party/{pma,wp-cli},conf/{nginx,php,crontab},local/tdm}.sh
```

The last goes a little against your wish to avoid a long line.

A vertical version that allows for empty lines:

```
parallel -rj1 ~/${repo}/{} <<_EOF
apt/security.sh
apt/lemp.sh
apt/certbot.sh
apt/misc.sh

third-party/pma.sh
third-party/wp-cli.sh

conf/nginx.sh
conf/php.sh
conf/crontab.sh

local/tdm.sh
_EOF
```

Comment: Thx! The files themselves should be in one long vertical list, not horizontal one.

Comment: How about the dirs?

Comment: The order of everything should be as I presented (sorry if it sounds harsh, really no such intention). All I try to save here is typing the paths time and again.